# Помогите поставить заглушку в тесте

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, google-test, google-mock

Есть метод, который нужно протестировать:

```
void DATA::setData(QString path)
{
...........................
    QDir dir(path);
    if (dir.exists()) {
        ...................
    }
}
```

Можно ли как-то поставить заглушку на dir.exists() так, чтобы exists возвратил true при вызове метода setData в тесте вне зависимости от переменной path?

P.S. использую Google Mock и Google Test.
Если знаете другие фреймворки с помощью которых возможно осуществить данное действие, буду благодарен.

Comment: Я не знаю можно ли сделать с помощью фреймворков, но могу предложить следующее: Вместо `QDir` в тестах задавать производный класс в котором реализовано нужное поведение `exist()`. Либо если это возможно генерировать перед тестом нужный файл а в конце теста его удалять.

Comment: Типа:
class mockQDir : publick QDir 
{ QString exists() {return true} }
? С генерацией не пойдет, так как это принципиально не решит вопроса создания заглушек объектов, использующихся в методе

Comment: Да примерно так

Comment: Никак нельзя. Чтобы было можно, нужно вместо `QDir` использовать интерфейс, вместо которого в тестах использовать класс-заглушку, а в реальном коде либо `QDir`, либо класс, содержащий `QDir` (второе предпочтительнее).

Comment: Посмотрел я `QDir`: второй вариант является единственно возможным, т.к. `QDir` не имеет нужных виртуальных функций.

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно постановить заглушку на метод exists() в классе QDir:

1. Создайте мок-объект для класса QDir с помощью Google Mock. Например:

```
    class MockQDir : public QDir
    
    {
    
    public:
    
        MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(exists, bool(const QString& path));
    
    };
```

2. В вашем тесте создайте экземпляр этого мок-объекта и установите ожидание для вызова метода exists():

```
    TEST(SomeTestSuite, SomeTestCase)

    {

        MockQDir mockDir;

        EXPECT_CALL(mockDir, exists(_)).WillRepeatedly(Return(true));

    
        // Теперь при вызове dir.exists() в тесте, он будет всегда возвращать true

    
        // Используйте mockDir вместо реального объекта QDir

    }
```